# Changing flash latency from 0 to 1 even with enabled prefetch slows execution on STM32

Tags: microcontroller, arm, stm32, flash, stm32f3

I have put all clock configuration to its default state, so an internal oscillator is running at 8 mhz. I have a delay loop using inline assembly as follows:

```
// Delay a certain number of cycles using glorious inline assembly.
void delay(uint32_t time) {
    asm volatile(
        "mov r4, #3                \n" // Divide time by three since the loop is
        "udiv %[time], %[time], r4 \n" // 3x too slow.
        "loop:                     \n"
        "subs %[time], %[time], #1 \n" // 1 cycle
        "bne loop                  \n" // 1 cycle if not take, 2 if taken.
        : [time] "+l" (time)           // Put rw input variable time in r0..r7.
                                       // Make it rw and as output so we don't clobber
        :                              // Time is both input and output.
        : "r4", "cc"                   // We are clobbering r4 and condition code flags.
    );
}
```

and a GPIO routine as follows:

```
// Blink the led with a period of 1 second.
while (1) {
    // Set LED pin.
    GPIOA_BSRR = 1 << LED_PIN;
    delay(second_cycles / 2);

    // Reset LED pin
    GPIOA_BSRR = 1 << (LED_PIN + 16);
    delay(second_cycles / 2);
}
```

When running without wait states everything is fine and performing as expected. But when I change the wait states for flash from 0 to 1, my loop takes 833 milliseconds instead of 500 milliseconds, or a 66% loss in performance roughly.

When I use GDB to debug, I can see the FLASH_ACR register has the contents of `0b0011 0000` which signify that the prefetch buffer is both enabled and has a status of enabled, with 0 wait states for flash. Plus, the prefetch buffer should be enabled on reset as per the datasheet. When I write to the register by or'ing it with `0b001` I get the expected result of `0b0011 0001` back after reading from it again. This is done doing the following:

```
// Change the flash wait states to 1.
volatile uint32_t foo1 = FLASH_ACR;
FLASH_ACR = FLASH_ACR | (0b001 << 0);
volatile uint32_t foo2 = FLASH_ACR;
```

Interestingly enough, enabling or disabling the prefetch buffer with a 1 wait state makes no difference in my loop, which doesn't seem to make sense.

And here is the relevant section of the datasheet[image: Flash ACR]

I am using an [NUCLEO-F303RE board](https://developer.mbed.org/platforms/ST-Nucleo-F303RE/), which uses an STM32F103RE.

Comment: The [datasheet](http://www.st.com/web/catalog/mmc/FM141/SC1169/SS1031/LN1565/PF164485) is not very helpful. My guess would be that the flash bus clock is *delayed by 1 Tcy* for FLASH_ACR = 0x01, and *delayed by 2* for 0x02, *regardless* of prefetch. Did you try 0x02 to see if it degrades another 66%?

Comment: I thought I saved the data related to when I change the wait state to 2 nut it seems I didn't. From what I remember, it was 1.2 to 1.5 seconds. I will recheck when I get home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cache buffer in STM32F303RE is only 8 bytes (64 bits) therefore if your cycle code is longer than 8 bytes it will have no effect because the buffer is rewritten each cycle again and again.  Here, the I-cache could help you but as i see there is no I-cache in this MCU.

It is preferable to use a timer sourced from an always constant clock, like 32.768 kHz or other oscillation, to count delays. Your MCU implements many timers and the RTC, try to use one.

```
void delay(unsigned timertickstowait)
{
  unsigned time0 = get_current_timer_ticks_count();
  while( (unsigned)(get_current_timer_ticks_count() - time0) < timertickstowait )
    { /* do nothing */ }
  return;
}
```

If the timer you use is sourced from a clock (frequency) independent from the MCU clock, the delay routine will be practically independent in its behavior from MCU frequency and/or Flash access parameters.